# How to serve zipped files over webpages so that it can extracted by a function and used by a library?

Tags: javascript, php, three.js

I making an application with threejs. Though I have optimised my 3d models very well, but still if I add up all the model sizes it it is a big amount like 100-150 Mb excluding textures. I observed if I zip the OBJ model the size comes down drastically, an 8mb obj becomes 2mb which is very surprising!!!

Is there any way I can load up the zip file, then somehow make it extract on the client side for further usage. Right now it's just the website, later on it will turn into a mobile app. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

most servers support sending gzipped files. Either you gzip them by hand or you configure the server to do it for you. The server sends the gzipped file to the browser. The browser decompresses it transparently meaning from your POV it doesn't look compressed. So there is no reason to send zip files. Just figure out how to send gzipped files from your server. You can check they were actually gzipped in the network tab of your brower's dev tools.

I can't tell you how to do it because it's specific to each server but you can google the name of your server and gzip or compression and probably find out how to do it.

As an example [this three.js example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_gltf.html) if we check the network tools and add the response->content encoding column we can see about half the files downloaded were gzipped

[image]

threejs.org is served off of github pages and github pages provides no way to configure how files are served. It chooses to gzip .js files and .gltf files but not .bin or .jpg files but on your own server you can configure it yourself.

You can also see from the Connection ID column that all the files were served over a single connection which is similar to serving them as a single file so no reason to put them in a single file as long as your server is configured correctly.

You can also see from the graph that many files were downloaded in parallel. Something that can't happen with a zip file. I have no idea which is faster over the network but the advantage to letting the server and the browser do this is they are much faster at decompressing and it requires no extra code in you page.

If you actually want to download zip files then you'll need [a zip library](https://greggman.github.io/unzipit) so you'll add more data to your page (the zip library itself) and whatever extra integration is needed to convert paths in your data into the blob URLs from the zip file plus you'll add the time it actually takes to decompress the file and the extra memory of having to have the zip file in memory to decompress it. Images for textures will be even worse since you'll first download the zip, then extract the image data from the zip. Then give that data back to the browser as a blob, then get a URL for that blob to turn it into an `<image>` so that you can then get the browser to decode it where as if you go letting the server/browser/http handle this all of that extra processing and memory go away.

Comment: Something ZIP can do and Gzip cannot is to pack many files in a single HTTP request.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, Browsers and servers already deal with multiple files via various parts of HTTP so just configure your server correctly and that problem is solved as well. If you check the "Connection ID" column in the network tab for the demo above you'll see github served all the files over a single connection which is effectively the same as zipping them into one file. You can also see by the graph they were downloaded in parallel. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/34184994/128511

Comment: I really meant request rather than connection. You still get a set of request/response headers for each individual file; that adds some overhead. I don't have expertise in game programming but I presume we aren't talking about a dozen assets. I understand and agree with the point of your answer anyway, this was just an extra hint. BTW, sending individual gzipped files can benefit from parallel downloads when using *different* connections. Reusing a connection means serial download, albeit without "gaps" between them because you don't need to close the connection and negotiate a new one.

Comment: I have feeling if you actually test, using a zip file will lose in every single cstgeory. slower to downlaod, slower to decompress, slower to prep for usage, also way worse on cache misses since if you chamge on tiny thing the entire zip has to get redowbloaded next visit. basically zip files are the wrong tool for web pages period.